# unexpected result while concatenating string in perl

Tags: perl

I am trying to execute below script but not getting desired output. it seems like it is still preserving old value and keep concatenating it.

./test.pl -v v10,v11,v12

Actual Result => 'v10','v11','v10','v12','v10','v11','v10'

Expected Result => 'v10','v11','v12'

can you please help resolve the issue?

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;
use Getopt::Long;

my ($versionFlag,$finalVersionList);

sub validateInputAndFilter
{
        my ($passedVersionList) = @_;
        $finalVersionList ="";

        my @versionList = split(",",$passedVersionList);
        foreach my $ver (@versionList)
        {
                if($ver =~ m/^v[0-9][0-9]$/)
                {
                        $finalVersionList .= "'$ver',$finalVersionList";
                }
                else
                {
                        print "\nWARNING: Passed version *** $ver *** is NOT in expected format...skipping...\n";
                }
        }
        $finalVersionList =~ s/\,$//;
        print "\n\nfinalVersionList => $finalVersionList\n\n";
}

GetOptions('v|version=s' => \$versionFlag) || die "Please pass version list separated by comma";

if(defined $versionFlag)
{
        &validateInputAndFilter("$versionFlag");
}
else
{
        die "Please pass version list separated by comma";
}
exit 0;
```

Comment: You should probably avoid using `$finalVersionList` as a global variable when you can so easily keep it lexical by using `return $finalVersionList` in the sub.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This:

```
$finalVersionList .= "'$ver',$finalVersionList";
```

Should just be :

```
$finalVersionList .= "'$ver,'";
```

`$foo .= $bar`; is equivalent to :

```
$foo = $foo . $bar;
```

So, `$finalVersionList .= "'$ver',$finalVerionList";` is equivalent to :

```
$finalVersionList = $finalVersionList . "'$ver',$finalVersionList";
```

Answer (score 2):

Change:

```
 $finalVersionList .= "'$ver',$finalVersionList";
```

To:

```
 $finalVersionList .= "'$ver',";
```

You're doing multiple appends here. What you had originally is equivalent to:

```
 $finalVersionList = $finalVersionList . "'$ver',$finalVersionList";
```

Which is not what you want. If you want `'$ver$',` to be at the fromt of the list, you could do:

```
$finalVersionList = "'$ver'," . $finalVersionList;
```

or:

```
 $finalVersionList = "'$ver',$finalVersionList";
```

Comment: Judging by his inputs and expected outputs, I actually think he wants to do `$finalVersionList .= "'$ver',";`